# Android Studio not recognizing KVM in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: kvm-virtualization, android-studio

Whenever I try to start a virtual device in android studio a message pops up saying:

```
KVM is required to run this AVD

No emulator installed

Please Download the emulator
```

So I followed the installation instructions for KVM on Ubuntu and verified that it is installed.

```
$ virish -c qemu:///system list
  Id    Name                           State
  ----------------------------------------------------
```

But I still get the same message.

Comment: do you have any AVDs - i mean created emulators?